# How can I authorize REST API for an application rather than for a user?

Tags: c#, api, authorization, azure-devops-rest-api

I have a mobile app, which needs to call a REST API. Here is my code:

```
        string url = $@"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/solutions/bookingBusinesses/{adTenantId}/appointments";

        string accessToken = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(AuthService.JwtToken);

        HttpClient client = new();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

This gives me error 401 (Unauthorized). I may be wrong, but it seems to me that it is because I use the access token based on the user's authentication. I probably need to call the API not as the user, but as my app. Buy I don't know how to get an access token for the app.
The app is registered with Azure AD and has necessary API permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Assume you have set up the app for MS Graph API correctly, and you have the below configurations:

- ClientId
- ClientSecret
- TenantId
- Scopes

```
var app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(ClientId)
                        .WithClientSecret(ClientSecret)
                        .WithAuthority(new Uri("https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + Tenant))
                        .Build();

string[] scopes = new string[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };

var result = await app.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes).ExecuteAsync();

var accessToken = result.AccessToken;
```

Note that I use scope `https://graph.microsoft.com/.default` for all the permissions you have assigned to the application. You could use more specific scopes.

[References](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/console-app-quickstart?pivots=devlang-dotnet-core).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, the first line of your code gives an exception: "System.PlatformNotSupportedException: Confidential Client flows are not available on mobile platforms or on Mac."  Is there any alternative?

Comment: So you have a mobile app, not a server app? There are some security concerns based on this doc if you want to access the Graph API from a client app. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-client-applications.

Comment: Yes, it it a mobile app. But we can store secrets on Azure, e.g. in Azure Key Vault...

Comment: I think it's not to do where you store the key but more on how OAuth2 flow works. In your case, if one of the mobile devices is compromised, the client secret will be used for unauthorised access. This is considered a security threat.

Comment: So it is the right way to call a REST Api? It has to be possible...